# Shaka player cannot load HLS on google chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, streaming, http-live-streaming, shaka

I'm trying to load a VOD on shaka player. 
this is my Url:

https://5b48f8f32d3be.streamlock.net/023a27950bd44774/mp4:22436e792e8b42de_HD.0.mp4/playlist.m3u8

---

I keep getting 4032 error in the console and I've searched a little bit about it. In the shaka document, the 4032 error has mentioned as CONTENT_UNSUPPORTED_BY_BROWSER. But when I'm testing my URL on the shaka player test URL everything is working fine.

https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/demo/#asset=https://storage.googleapis.com/shaka-demo-assets/angel-one/dash.mpd;lang=en-US;build=uncompiled

if my browser was the problem, it shouldn't play on the test URL too.
What should I have to do to shaka support HLS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Much of the HLS content out there has MPEG2-TS streams, which many browsers don't support.  To work around this issue, Shaka Player supports transmuxing TS to MP4 so the browser can play it.  This is done using the [mux.js](https://github.com/videojs/mux.js/) library.  This library needs to be loaded in a separate script tag before Shaka Player is loaded.  For example, here is how the Shaka Player [demo does it](https://github.com/google/shaka-player/blob/39df7a3d8ef61ac4a2606c07411e8fe0191b1893/demo/index.html#L38).

Answer (score 0):

Add this two files in the index.html file.

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mux.js@5.5.3/dist/mux.min.js">  </script>`

`<!-- Load the Shaka Player library -->`

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/shaka-player@3.2.2/dist/shaka-player.compiled.js"></script>`

This should be able to transmux MPEG2-TS streams to MP4 so they can be played in browsers that don't support it. And this helps in changing the resolution of the video.

And use const shaka = require("shaka-player/dist/shaka-player.ui.js");
instead of shaka-player package.